# value in this form "ws$B$16", get the data of that entire row upto column Z output to master ws C2. Value of ws & cell changes depend on search info

Tags: excel, vba

Still a newbie with VBA coding. I have a code to search input text or word (ignore case sensitive) from a multiple worksheet, text/word can be within a word (ex. ben from Benjamin). So far, i have the result of search in column B2, C2, D2 and so on until done. the value in column B2, C2, D2 have same format WS.name & cell address in the form of dog$B$, cat$D$32, horse$F200, etc. I want the Display output into a Master worksheet to column A3:whatever.  The output should consist of that entire row including bland cell upto column Z. Also if the worksheet name is calling for "chart" I also need the value of the rows from 3 rows before and 2 rows after.

Comment: If you need help modifying your code then including it in your post would be a good thing to do.

Comment: Here is what i have so far

Comment: 'I need to integrate following:'
Sub GotoSheet()
    Dim sSheet As String
    Dim rowcol As String
    sSheet = InputBox( _
      Prompt:="What is the name of WorkSheet?", _
      Title:="Input Sheet")
    rowcol = InputBox( _
      Prompt:="What is the row & column number (example: A45)?", _
      Title:="Input: ")
    On Error Resume Next
    If Val(sSheet) > 0 Then
        Worksheets(Val(sSheet)).Activate
    Else
        Worksheets(sSheet).Activate
    End If
    Call Goto_myCell
End Sub
Sub Goto_myCell()
Application.Goto Range(rowcol).Value, Scroll:=True
End Sub